# Can I travel to the UK if my Schengen visa expired? but I have a valid multiple visiting visa for UK

Tags: visas, schengen, uk

Can I travel to the UK if my Schengen visa expired?

I'm from Sri Lanka and I got 6 months multiple visit visa for UK and 1 month Schengen tourist visa for Italy. my plan was to visit my sister in UK then go to Italy to visit my brother and then go back to UK wait another 3 weeks and from there back to Sri lanka.

At first I went to UK on 12/08/2014 and stayed 8 days and then I came to Italy on 20/08/2014 my plan was to go back to UK but unfortunately I got very sick and I wasn't able to travel. Now my Schengen visa expired but I have a visa for UK until 17/12/2014.

I want to know can I renter to UK with my Schengen visa expired but with a valid multiple visiting visa for UK.

Comment: Are you in breach on your Schengen?

Comment: yes I guess :(  @Gayot Fow

Comment: yes I guess :( @GayotFow

Comment: Note that the Schengen area has exit immigration. You will need to show your passport, your visa and your entry stamp upon leaving the area (to the UK or elsewhere) and could be fined for overstaying. It is in fact possible to extend a Schengen visa for “serious personal reasons” but I suspect it might be too late now. If you are still in Italy, you could still try.

Answer (score 3):

You can travel to the UK, but having a successful landing interview may present problems.

You're in breach on your Schengen, and this would need to be disclosed to the IO because it is a material change in circumstances (Paragraph 321 (ii) and (iii)).  If you chose to disclose it, you will need to think up a good explanation in order to convince the IO that you are not a risk.

If you chose NOT to disclose, and the IO discovers it on his own, you will then be in trouble and getting bounced is almost a certainty.  Because you did not disclose material facts, your transcript MAY contain a reference to Paragraph 320 of the rules.  It's a bad position to be in because your credibility has been blown.

Alternatively, if you chose NOT to disclose and the IO does not notice it, you're good to go.  The next time you apply for a visitor's visa, however, will be difficult if they spot it when the consulate inspects your passport.  If they spot it, you'll be logged as an illegal entrant.

The IO is entitled to bounce someone under Paragraphs 10 and 10B of the rules.  If Paragraph 320 (7b)(d) is used as the grounds, then forget visiting the UK for a while.

If your landing interview is not successful, you'll be bounced (i.e., turned around, refused entry, etc)

**Adding**: when you applied for a UK entry clearance, you signed an agreement to notify them of any changes in your circumstances.

Comment: @Nu2000 If you opt to disclose, you will need to think up something. As much documentation as you can find will be helpful. I like pnuts idea to report yourself in the Schengen zone and bring that along also.  As to your thanks, please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @pnuts, that should be an answer also.  Note that in these cases, it's usually better to gather up any and all available docs and THEN backfit the reason, rather than vice-versa. But your comments should be an answer anyway.

Comment: @pnuts, they don't care where the breach occurred, I have seen them bounce for an overstay in Egypt! A Schengen breach is only marginally worse because there are technical problems about where they should be bounced to. :) A breach is a breach :)

Comment: @pnuts, as a fellow Brit, you would be aware that the UK is in an orbit unto its own, in fact universe unto itself where visas are concerned :)

Comment: Im going to take my return ticket and latter from the doctor as my prof. Do u think this ll be enough for me to go through ?  @pnuts

Comment: Im going to take my return ticket and latter from the doctor as my prof. Do u think this ll be enough for me to go through ?  @GayotFow

Comment: @Nu2000, that's a different question.

Comment: I didnt get you @GayotFow

Comment: @Nu2000, it's not part of this question; it's a different question altogether